# Passing cmd parameters to Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I would like to pass command line parameters to my Node.js/Jasmine tests. At the moment I have basic Jasmine file/dir structure set up (jasmine.json file and specs - as in the example: [Jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.2/node.html)).

I run specs from command line by executing the following command:`jasmine`.

I would like to pass some command line parameter, so that I can use it **in my specs**. I would run tests with the following command:`jasmine --param value` or  `jasmine param_value`.
Is it possible (how to do that)?

The parameter I want to pass is a password and I don't want to hardcode it - maybe you can suggest any better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than passing credentials as a command line parameter, I often see people use environment variables, which you can grab from Node using `process.env.SUPERSECRETPASSWORD`.

Comment: That's the idea - thanks! Nevertheless, command line parameters could be helpful for different purposes - my question is still valid then.

Comment: [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) is probably a good starting point then - only caveat I'd add is that you should probably prefix your parameter name with something specific to you/your company, just to make absolutely sure Jasmine doesn't add a parameter with the same name and cause havoc :)

Comment: Jasmine uses '--' to signal the end of its command parameters and that's why.

Answer (score 0):

First off in general if you want to send parameters to a test in jasmine you would use `jasmine -- --param value` or `jasmine -- param_value`. No that extra `--` isn't a typo it tells jasmine to ignore everything after that and pass it on.

That said passwords and the command-line parameters don't mix. Virtually every shell has some form of history. That history will record every command just as its typed. This is major security no no. It leaves an unencrypted password recorded on disk.

The test itself should ask for the password if that needs to be supplied without hard-coding. This will at most generate a transient in memory temporary with the value. That is must safer then having it in a history file somewhere. node has modules such as readline that can do this without generating visible output for the password being entered.